# Remove spaces and underscores from a T List

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, removing-whitespace

Problem: 
A T list of object (aTSource) contains a list of field names with extra spaces and underscores preventing matches to a variable without.

I have a T list of object from my Model class. This list includes a Field name, value and the field type. I want to go into the field names and remove any spaces and underscores from the name.

The purpose of the code is to compare fields from an Excel document and WPF form and return a list of those field names in common.

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList())
{
    T aTSource = new T();
    foreach (PropInfo aField in commonFields)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfos = aTSource.GetType().GetProperty(aField.Name);
        var value = (dataRow[afield.Name] == DBNull.Value) ? null : dataRow[afield.Name]; 
        ...     
        propertyInfos.SetValue(aTSource, value, null);
        list.Add(aTSource);
    }
}
```

Sample values from aTSource:

```
IP_Address     null  string
Product Name   null  string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two Foreach loops with replacement statements, the first for the list of Excel field names and the second for the WPF form of field names, to ensure that the field names both match.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
{
    column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "");
    column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName.Replace("_", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just compare two strings, independent of spaces and underscores, you can create an extension method that would strip them and then do the compare:

```
public static string SuperStrip(this string InputString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InputString))
        return string.Empty;

    return InputString.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("_", string.Empty);
}
```

Each of these expressions would then result in a `true` condition:

```
bool foo;
foo = "nicekitty".SuperStrip() == "nice kitty".SuperStrip();
foo = "nicekitty".SuperStrip() == "nice_kitty".SuperStrip();
foo = "nice_kitty".SuperStrip() == "nice kitty".SuperStrip();
```

Of course, you could also wrap that in a single function to compare them:

```
public static bool HeaderCompare(string String1, string String2)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String1))
        String1 = string.Empty;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String2))
        String2 = string.Empty;

    return String1.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("_", string.Empty) ==
        String2.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("_", string.Empty);
}
```

This almost seems oversimplified, so it's possible I misunderstood your task, so if I'm off feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I was really looking for a way to change the field names of a T list. "IP_Address" would become "IPAddress" and "Product Name" would become "ProductName". I ended up solving this problem by replacing the underscore and blank spaces with another character "^" and then doing a comparison for that new character.